# i am having a small issue with tkinter python gui element

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, scrollbar

i am trying to place a scrollbar next to a listbox .NOTE: i am using place() method i have to stick to it because of some reasons. i know how to do it with grid() and pack() . but i am unable to achieve the same with place().

```
here is the part of my code:


data = Listbox(root, width=33, height=15,bg='grey',fg='black')
data.place(x=381,y=158)
# create a vertical scrollbar to the right of the data
yscroll = Scrollbar(command=data.yview, orient=VERTICAL)
#......this is causing trouble...........
yscroll.place(x=580,y=158)
#..........................................
data.configure(yscrollcommand=yscroll.set)
#data.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>',openDoc)

#test function for  listbox
def populate():
    for i in range(1,50):
        data.insert('end','number is: '+str(i))
```

whwat modification i need to make so that scrollbar expands?

Comment: Have you tried the [`anchor`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/place.htm) option?

Comment: Causing trouble meaning what? It's with expanding?

Comment: @TheMonk yeah the trouble is with expanding. with grid() i can do sticky('news') it works, but with place there is no sticky option.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 with anchor there is nothing like NS(north-south) as  with sticky.how do i get that?

Comment: It seems to have options like `SE` and `NW`. Did you try `NS`? Or maybe try `in_`? Can you `place()` something like a `Frame` and then just `grid()` or `pack()` the `Listbox` and `Scrollbar` into that?

Comment: i tried NS that option isnt there SE AND NW are valid but dosent work? how to place a frame?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3  thanks , i figured it out

Answer (score 2):

Using `grid` or `pack` will almost always yield a GUI that is easier to maintain and is more resilient in the face of change (different fonts, different resolutions, a resized window). The simplest solution is to use a frame, pack the scrollbar on the right and the listbox on the left, and then you can treat the whole frame+listbox+scrollbar as a single widget within the rest of the GUI. This is a very common technique.

However, if you insist on using `place` and only `place`, and want it next to the listbox, the best choice is to use a combination of relative and absolute positioning.

With relative positioning you can tell place "put this next to this other widget", and not have to worry about the exact coordinates yourself. You can also tell place to make the widget exactly as tall (or wide) as some other widget, or exactly some fraction of a size of another widget. In your case you want the scrollbar to be exactly as tall as the listbox.

Here is a complete working example which builds on your code:

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.geometry("800x800")
data = Listbox(root, width=33, height=15,bg='grey',fg='black')
data.place(x=381,y=158)
# create a vertical scrollbar to the right of the data
yscroll = Scrollbar(command=data.yview, orient=VERTICAL)

yscroll.place(relx=1.0, y=0.0, relheight=1.0, 
              bordermode="outside", in_=data)

data.configure(yscrollcommand=yscroll.set)
#data.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>',openDoc)

#test function for  listbox
def populate():
    for i in range(1,50):
        data.insert('end','number is: '+str(i))
populate()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, handling resize smoothly are one of the main goal of geometry managers *pack* and *grid*. It is not recommended to mix *pack* and *grid* in the same container, but one of them could work along *place*, and generally mixing different geometry managers is achieved through intermediate frames. For you precise example: create a `Frame` in root with `place`, then in this frame, create the `Listbox` and `Scrollbar` with either pack or grid.

If you stick with *place*, [`place`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/place.htm#Tkinter.Place.place-method) accept an optional argument name `height` that force the widget to a given height. As for the value to provide, you can wait for the listbox to be displayed to access its pixel height (the `height` provided in `Listbox` constructor is in lines). `<Configure>` event is raised each time widget display parameter is altered, and so on its first drawing.

```
def updateYScrollPosition(*event):
    yscroll.place(
        x=data.winfo_x() + data.winfo_width(),
        y=data.winfo_y(),
        height=data.winfo_height())

data.bind("<Configure>", updateYScrollPosition)
```

Comment: _"It is not recommended to mix pack and grid in the same container"_ is putting it mildly. It's more than just "not recommended", simply put it should _never_ be done.